# Problem in adding two Schunk arms plus a simple shape (e.g. cylinder) into .urdf.xacro

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Friends,
First of all, I apologize if my question may look trivial. I am new with ROS.
Here is the problem: The aim is to have two Schunk arms mounted on a simple box.
We have a robot.urdf.xacro file. This file "includes" the model of the arm:

```
<xacro:include filename="$(find schunk_description)/urdf/lwa4d/lwa4d.urdf.xacro" />
```

And uses it twice to have two arms:

```
<!-- arm -->
<xacro:schunk_lwa4d name="arm" parent="world" has_podest="true">
 <origin xyz="0 0 0.026" rpy="0 0 0" />
</xacro:schunk_lwa4d>

 <!-- arm2 -->
<xacro:schunk_lwa4d name="arm2" parent="world" has_podest="true">
 <origin xyz="0.5 0.5 0.526" rpy="0 0 0" />
</xacro:schunk_lwa4d>
```

And then when I spawn the xacro file in launch file, 2 arms are loaded in Gazebo. Till here seems fine!
But adding a simple shape to this set was/is a pain for me.
I define a ros package, called *myschunk_gazebo*. Then I try to include one simple .xacro file including only a box (or cylinder) in myschunk_gazebo/models and I call the file simple_shape.xacro.
I know that ROS can locate the package. I check it with rospack:

```
ros@ros:~/Documents/Damon_CPP/ROS_Workspace/devel$ rospack find myschunk_gazebo
/home/ros/Documents/Damon_CPP/ROS_Workspace/src/myschunk_gazebo
```

But from here the problem starts!
Well, as I know, even this simple shape is called a "robot". So I write simple_shape.xacro. like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="myfirst">
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
</robot>
```

When I launch the file, only the empty space is loaded in gazebo. And between many messages, I thought this might be useful to be put in here:

`Failed to find root link: Two root links found: [base_link] and [world]`

I guess I know what is going on. We should have only one , which I have in my urdf.xacro file that I spawn in my launch file. But what I do when I include simple_shape.xacro is that I have two  s. And hence, two root links.

I remove the lines related to robot and change simple_shape.xacro to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
    <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
```

I also include base_link in my robot.urdf.xacro file:

```
<link name="base_link"/>
```

And loads only empty space.
I don't think the inclusion of the file should be a problem. But I highly doubt if I use the shape in robot.urdf.xacro properly, or my codes for generating the shape are correct.

It would be so nice if a friend can clarify for me what is going on.
Thanks. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213391/problem-in-adding-two-schunk-arms-plus-a-simple-shape-(e.g.-cylinder)-into-.urdf.xacro/) by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tl;dr: you probably forgot to add a joint between `world` and your box/cylinder's `base_link`.

---

Longer version: a `urdf` (which is what the `.xacro` files are turned into before Gazebo or anything else in ROS gets to them) models a scene as a *tree*. So every link needs to be connected to another. Forests (set of disconnected trees, or islands of links) are not allowed.

In your case, the two calls to `xacro:schunk_lwa4d` supply that macro with two important arguments:

1. `parent="world"`
2. `<origin xyz="0 0 0.026" rpy="0 0 0" />`

Argument 1 is used internally in `xacro:schunk_lwa4d` to setup a `fixed` joint (or *parent-child* relation) between a link *outside* of the `schunk_lwa4d` macro called `world` and the root of the LWA 4D ([here](https://github.com/ipa320/schunk_modular_robotics/blob/c6b3686c0c130fb72044dd8927e290d9ba00be60/schunk_description/urdf/lwa4d/lwa4d.urdf.xacro#L14)). One of those two links will be made the *root* of the LWA 4D model, depending on the `has_podest` argument.

Argument 2 then defines the relative transform between that `world` link and the `${name}_podest_link` [here](https://github.com/ipa320/schunk_modular_robotics/blob/c6b3686c0c130fb72044dd8927e290d9ba00be60/schunk_description/urdf/lwa4d/lwa4d.urdf.xacro#L15) (in case `has_podest=true`), or [here](https://github.com/ipa320/schunk_modular_robotics/blob/c6b3686c0c130fb72044dd8927e290d9ba00be60/schunk_description/urdf/lwa4d/lwa4d.urdf.xacro#L46) for `${name}_base_link` if you have `has_podest=false`.

Now the `world` link can either be predefined by Gazebo, or added by you to your *composite* xacro (I use the term composite to mean an `xacro` that does not really define anything new itself, but is a collection of instantiations of other `xacro:macro`s). In all cases you end up with a tree structure, in which `world` is the root.

> ```
> Failed to find root link: Two root links found: [base_link] and [world]
> ```

This should now be obvious, but in the case where you added the box/cylinder, you seem to not have defined any joint linking the `base_link` (or its *root*) of your box to the rest of the scene. That results in two forests (ie: islands) and that is not allowed in `urdf` (and so Gazebo can't work with it either).

Solution: define a joint (probaby a `fixed` one) which fixes your box/cylinder in your scene, using `origin` to define the relative transform between the parent and the `base_link` of your new addition (or whatever you end up naming the root of your model).

---

Note also that all links in a `urdf` must be uniquely named: you cannot have two `base_link`s. This is why most `xacro`s include a `prefix` or `name` parameter, which is prefixed to all internally defined links. It essentially *namespaces* all links, allowing you to instantiate a single `xacro` macro multiple times, by using different values for the prefix (in your case `arm` and `arm2`). You should probably do something similar with your box/cylinder. See [wiki/urdf/Tutorials - Using Xacro to Clean Up a URDF File: Leg macro](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File#Leg_macro) for an example.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-07-23**:
Dear gvdhoorn,
Thank you so much for your answer. The reason that I am replying late is that I realized I need to learn urdf more deeply. So I started from the beginning and at the end I was able to solve the problem. I will write my experience here in the form of an answer soon.
Thanks again. :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-28**:
Ok. If you feel this answer has answered your question, please indicate that by ticking the checkmark.

**Comment by [Damon](https://answers.ros.org/users/22801/damon/) on 2015-07-29**:
Ow, Ok. I will do so. Plus, if anybody else is reading this, I should mention again that I will write the problem and the solution more in detail as soon as I have time (right now I have 15 days to my thesis deadline! :( )